# Android custom video capture file path not working

Tags: android, video, filenames, video-capture, android-intent

I'm working in an application that should launch the camera application by using intents; the camera is launched in picture or video mode and so far it works and save the resulting file in sdcard. Now the problem is that, while specifiying a new custom filename works for the picture intent, it seems not to be working for the camcorder intent; in fact, EXTRA_OUTPUT or simply "output" seems to get ignored in the video intent. I'm using the following codes:

For the pictures (all works wonder, including saving the pic with a custom filename)

```
// makes new unique filenames like Picture_03161185528.jpg
fileName = makeFileName("Picture")+".jpg";
path = (new StringBuilder()).
            append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).
            append("/"+fileName).toString();
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("output", outputFileUri);        
mainActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

For the video (it takes the video BUT always use the default name like VIDEO001, VIDEO002, etc, not the custom filename I need)

```
// makes new unique filenames like Video_03161185528.3gp        
fileName = makeFileName("Video")+".3gp";
// even tried this hardwired filename...but nothing
fileName = "video.3gp";
path = (new StringBuilder()).
            append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).
            append("/"+fileName).toString();
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
// seems to be ignored, the file always get saved under default filename
intent.putExtra("output", outputFileUri);      
// same as previous line...seems to be ignored
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
mainActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_RESULT);
```

In any case, the picture intent saves the pictures with my custom file names, but the video intent plainly ignores it and always save the files using the default file names. My question is:

a) is there any way I can make this work using custom filenames?
b) or alternatively is there any way to know the next available default file name forehand?
c) or there is any other way to know which file was made and then rename it?

Cheers and thank you!

Aram

Comment: did u find any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I insert a row in the mediastore which gives me the uri of the future video before calling the intent. Once you have the uri, you can make any action you want on the file.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "video name");                                 
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,System.currentTimeMillis());                  
//videoUri = mediastore path    
videoUri = CaptureContentFragment.this.getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);                  
//create new Intent                     
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 20);
CaptureContentFragment.this.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, TabsActivity.VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```